# Python cant concentrate on int only on string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm able to use `""` and type a number as if it was reading text but if I try to run with only just a number and no quotations, or even with `int(x)`, I get the same error,

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Please do not post images of your code.

Comment: You can only concatenate string, you need to transform your int in string in order to concatenate

Comment: try `str(x)` instead of `int(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate integers with string, should convert it to string.

try:

```
age=20
print(" This is your " + str(age) + ".")
```

Or:

```
age=20
print(" This is your " , age, ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

you shold use formatted strings;
`f'your age is {variable storing your age}'`

More specifically as per your problem;
`"He is {character_age} years old"`.

Comment: Formatted strings help to put a variable inside a string. here i am using the character_age variable inside the string.

Comment: Why you get error? Because you cannot join an int with string. Because when you try to do so, you are adding a number with some letters which doesnot make any sense.